# Error value flatMap is not a member of Product with Serializable in for with Future[Option]

Tags: scala

The following block of code fails to build with error :

```
value flatMap is not a member of Product with Serializable
[error]         if (matchingUser.isDefined) {
```

Here's the code:

```
for {
  matchingUser <- userDao.findOneByEmail(email)
  user <- {
    if (matchingUser.isDefined) {
      matchingUser.map(u => {
        // update u with new values...
        userDao.save(u)
        u
      })
    } else {
      val newUser = new User(email)
      userDao.create(newUser)
      newUser
    }
  }
} yield user
```

Method `userDao.findOneByEmail(email) returns an`Future[Option[User]]`object.
My Google searches are only about`Either`with`Right`and`Left` types.

Maybe I'm not doing this the proper way, please teach me how to properly do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first branch of the `if` statement returns `Option[User]`, the other one returns `User`. So, the result of the entire statement is inferred to have type `Product with Serializable` because it is the only common supertype of the two.

You could wrap the last statement inside the `if` into an `Option` (just do `Option(newUser)` instead of `newUser`) or, better yet, use `fold` instead of the whole `if(matchingUser.isDefined) {...}` thingy:

```
 matchingUser.fold { 
   val u = new User(email)
   userDao.create(u)
   u
 } { u => 
   userDao.save(u)
   u
 }
```

This will make the result of that statement to be `Option[User]` as you probably intended ... but it still will not compile. 
The problem is that you cannot mix different types of monads in the for-comprehension: since the first one was `Future`, all the others have to be as well. You can't have an `Option` there.

How to get around that? Well, one possibility is to make `userDao.create` and `userDao.save` return a future of the object they just saved. That is, probably a better thing to do in general, then what you have, because now you are returning the user before it was actually stored ... What if the `create` operation fails afterwards? Then you can just rewrite your for-comprehension like this:

```
for {
  matchingUser <- userDao.findOneByEmail(email)
  user <- matchingUser.fold(userDao.create(new User(email)))(userDao.save)
} yield user
```

Or just get rid of it entirely (for-comprehension is an overkill for simple cases like this):

```
  userDao
   .findOneByEmail(email)
   .flatMap(_.fold(usrDao.create(new User(email)))(userDao.save))
```

Or, it may look a little nicer with pattern matching instead of `fold` in this case:

```
 userDao
   .findOneByEmail(email)
   .flatMap { 
      case Some(u) => userDao.save(u)
      case None => userDao.create(new User(email))
    }
```

Comment: You're right on persist/update methods should return the persisted/updated record instead of Future[Unit]. You're also right that if my code was as simple as what I posted, for would be overkill but in reality, I simplified my code quite a bit before posting ensuring my question was straight to the problem and nothing more. Also good point about the fold method, I was unaware of it until your answer. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm done refactoring everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test example to reproduce your issue with solution.
Basically your `user` returns wrapper around Future (Option of Future), but it expected to be Future, as the first statement in for-comprehension.
That is why I've applied some addition unwrapping. See sample below.

Note: it does not looks so nice, I'd prefer to rewrite it with flatMap map.

```
object T {

  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def future1: Future[Option[Int]] = ???

  def future2(i: Int): Future[Double] = ???

  for {
    matchingUser <- future1
    user <- {
      if (matchingUser.isDefined) {
        matchingUser.map { i =>
          future2(i)
        }
      } else {
        Some(future2(42))
      }
    } match {
      case None => Future.successful(-42.0)
      case Some(x) => x
    }
  } yield user
}
```

And the same implemented with flatMap:

```
  val userFuture = future1.flatMap { 
      case Some(i) => future2(i)
      case None => future2(42)
  }
```

Comment: You can also use partial function syntax (`future1.flatMap { case Some(i) => ...`) instead of matching directly